# Can we change the color of error message in lightning-input (LWC)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css

I am using the following code to show input field in LWC.

```
<lightning-input placeholder="First"
    onchange={handleContactFieldValueChange}
    data-apiname="FirstName"
    required
    value={contactObject.FirstName}>
</lightning-input>
```

Can we change the color of the error message?

By default, it's **red**.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) to see which properties and styling hooks are supported?

Comment: Yes, I checked these both: 
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Styling-Hooks-Overview

and 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification

Answer (score 1):

we have to override CSS of standard lwc component :

Create a CSS file and add in static resource
File Content :

```
.slds-form-element__help {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Import That static resource file in your component

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CUSTOMCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/{yourfileName}';
```

a) Define variable like : isCssLoaded = false;

Call it in reRenderCallback

```
renderedCallback(){

if(this.isCssLoaded) return
this.isCssLoaded = true;
loadStyle(this,CUSTOMCSS).then(()=>{
    console.log('loaded');
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log('error to load');
});
}
```